# Power Automate get data from Project Online and Filter

Tags: power-automate, project-online

I am using "Send an HTTP Request to Sharepoint" action, and I want to filter the output to only include the project with ID = [user input filed in "Manually trigger a flow"]

My Uri seems to not be working and can't find errors; I have used this action before with no problems, can't figure what syntax (?) problem I may have?

Here is the Uri:

```
_api/ProjectData/Projects()?$Filter=ProjectUID eq '@{variables('proj id')}'&?Select=ProjectName,ProjectWorkspaceInternalUrl,ProjectUID,ProjectIdentifier
```

Can anyone spot the problem?!
Thanks so much in advance :)

Comment: so you want to be able to extract the project ID? Can you take a screenshot of your flow please?

Answer (score -1):

For the URI try the following instead:

/_api/ProjectData/Projects()?$filter=ProjectId eq guid'xxxxx' &$Select=ProjectName,ProjectWorkspaceInternalUrl,ProjectId,ProjectIdentifier

where xxxx is your project id or in this case **@{variables('proj id')}**

It makes it easier to deal with the data as it doesn't return an array.